# How to list all component log detail level via jython script in Websphere (8.x)?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

is it possible to list all currently (at runtime) available components for which you can change the log level?
So you don't have to know the exact name beforehand for some deployed application.
E.g a command  listing all available loggers for server1 in a websphere cluster.

Thank you,
ralf

Comment: I don't know, if it is possible via scripting, but you can go to admin console `Troubleshooting > Logs and Traces > serverName > Change log level` to see all available loggers.

Comment: Thank you - do you know how to 'export' all the loggers shown?
Or whether the feature 'Enable command assistance notifications' can be used in the view (I didn't get it to work)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to export all loggers you could write very simple servlet/jsp to print all registered loggers, like this (I know, its not jython, but maybe it will be still useful for you):

```
@WebServlet("/LoggerTest")
public class LoggerTest extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();

        Enumeration<String> loggerNames = logManager.getLoggerNames();
        while (loggerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String loggerName = (String) loggerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println(loggerName);
        }
    }
}
```